# Error compiling in C [ error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’ ... ]

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

When I want to compile the `Raci.c` file by executing `gcc Raci.c`, I get the following error :

`Raci.c:32:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘WinMain’ 32 | int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {`

I've been trying to find the solution for a long time and I can't find it.

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a 'stupid' bug I've been studying C on my own for a short time.

I attach the content of `Raci.c` :

```
       │ File: Raci.c
#include<stdio.h>     // Libreria estandar para valores entrada/salida
#include<stdlib.h>    // Define 4 variables, macros y otras funciones generales
#include<unistd.h>    // Proporciones acceso a la API de POSIX (Operating System Interface). Estander IEEE que permite compatibilidad entre diferente S.O.

#ifdef _WIN32
#include<winsock2.h>  // Nos permite establecer conexiones con el servidor
#include<windows.h>   // Definimos que trabajaremos con Windows y nos aporta compatibilidad con ciertas funciones
#include<winuser.h>   // Permite diferentes funciones Windows Based
#include<wininet.h>   // Permite conexiones inet (detallar)
#include<windowsx.h>  // Mas compatibilidad Windows
#endif

#include<string.h>    // Permite manipular arrays de characteres comodamente (strings(
#include<sys/stat.h>  // Libreria C POSIX que contiene construcciones que facilitan obtención de información sobre atributos de archivos
#include<sys/types.h> // Diferentes variables y estructuras...


/*
Función main/prinicpal donde estableceremos conexión con el servidor y especificaremos el resto de funciones.

APIENTRY => Alias de WINAPI (Explicamos al compilador como manejar el stack y argumentos al llamar la función)


        PARAMETERS :

        HINSTANCE hInstance => Identificador de instancia / modulo. El S.O. utiliza este valor para identificar el EXE cuando es cargador en memoria.
        HINSTANCE hPrev     => Identificador de instancia previo
        LPSTR lpCmdLine     => Contiene la linea de comandos en un String Unicode (Nos da la shell utilizando un charset en casi todos los idiomas (UNICODE))
        int nCmdShow        => Indicador de tamaño de ventana CMD (pequeña, grande, invisible ...)
*/

// Inicialización de variables que deben ser aplicadas en otras funciones
int sock;

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

        // Inicializaciones de consola

        HWND stealth; // Identificador de ventana parte de Win32 API
        AllocateConsole(); // Inicializa nueva consola permitiendo entrada / salida y control de errores de esta misma.
        stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL); // Función para encontrar la ventana con ClassName "ConsoleWindowClass" sin especificar titulo. Busca la ventana / proceso

        ShowWindow(stealth,0); // Inicializamos la consola sin mostrarla

        struct sockaddr_in ServAddr; // Definición multiple de variables sockaddr_in y ServAddr
        unsigned short ServPort;     // Inicializamos variable unsigned (solo valores positivos) de tipo integer short
        char *ServIP;                // Inicializamos el pointer *ServIP
        WSDATA wsaData;              // Estructura que contiene información relacionada con sockets de Windows (Define como el software de aplicación accede a servidores de red especialmente TCP/IP)

        ServIP = "192.168.1.133";    // Indicamos la IP del servidor que esperará conexión (localhost)
        ServPort = "50005";          // Puerto por el que escucharemos / esperaremos conexión


        // Tratamos de inicializar Winsock DLL para el proceso de la aplicación. Si = 0 OK | Si != 0 WRONG
        if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData) != 0) {
                exit(1);
        }

        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0); // AF_INET => Indicamos que estableceremos conexión sobre IPv4
                                               // SOCK_STREAM => Indicamos que trabajaremos sobre el protocolo TCP

        memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));         // Limpiamos los bytes a 0 todo el contenido
        Serv.Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 // Especificamos que es IPv4
        Serv.Addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ServIP);  // Formateamos a IPv4 la IP introducida en ServIP
        Serv.Addr/sin_port = htons(ServPort);           // Especificamos y formateamos el puerto introducido 

        // IP:PUERTO

        connect(sock, (struct))

} // Main function end
```

Comment: Sorry for the comments in Spanish. I am attentive to the comments

Comment: First, make sure `_WIN32` is actually defined.  (One way is to put an erroneous statement inside your `#ifdef _WIN32` block and make sure the compiler shows an error there when you compile.)  Then make sure that one of your Windows headers is actually giving you a definition of `APIENTRY`.  You might also just try removing `APIENTRY` altogether.

Comment: It also is very likely that this code is not the problem, but a configuration problem, _eg_, trying to output a command-line programme when you appear to want a Windows executable. Could you tell us more about the tool-chain you used? `-mwindows` if `gcc`?

Comment: Please [edit] to remove the totally obnoxious line numbering decorations. Code should be formatted so that we can easily copy/paste it and compile it to help you troubleshoot it. See also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Okay, i'll do right now

Answer (score 1):

`APIENTRY` is not defined in any of the headers included by your program.

For a program using the Windows API, you should define `_WIN32` on the compiler command line so it includes the OS specific headers that define all these symbols and types...

Try: `gcc -D_WIN32 Raci.c -o Raci.o`

As commented by *David Grayson*, your compiler might not be installed  correctly to compile Windows programs.

Comment: also `HINSTANCE, hPrev` => `HINSTANCE hPrev`

Comment: @0___________ Yep, already fixed that!

Comment: @chqrlie So what should be the modify??

Comment: `APIENTRY` is documented by Microsoft actually, for use on WinMain function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain   And `_WIN32` should be automatically defined by any compiler compiling a native Windows program.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: then the version of `gcc` used by the OP might not be a windows enabled version.

Comment: @chqrlie Using gcc version 11.2.0

Comment: But GCC 11.2.0 can be configured to target different platforms and maybe it's not building native Windows apps, but instead building for Cygwin or something.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question in case this resolves the same error for someone.

When wanting to compile the C `Raci.c` file by executing a `gcc Raci.c` the error occurs:

```
Raci.c:32:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘WinMain’ 32 | int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
```

This is due to the fact that the `gcc` compiler has Linux-based systems as "target / destination" and when wanting to compile headers / headers with "target / destination", Windows based skips the above error.

**Excerpt from the line that indicates target from gcc:**
`gcc -v : Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`

**Solution**
Using the `mingw32` package we can compile and link headers to Windows on our Linux system.

- Install mingw32 => `apt install mingw-64`
- Example to compile / use x64-bit => `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g ++ [file.c]`
- Example to compile / use 32-bit => `i686-w64-mingw32-g ++ [file.c]`

Comment: I hope I have explained the solution in detail